# PHP Autoload with namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I have set up directories as followers:

```
App/index.php
App/src/db.php
App/config/config.php
```

App/index.php:

```
<?php
use App\Src;

require 'config/config.php';

$db = new DB();
?>
```

App/src/db.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Src;
class DB { }
?>
```

App/config/config.php:

```
<?php
set_include_path(dirname(__DIR__));
spl_autoload_register();
?>
```

What is it that I don't understand here...
Index.php fails with a "Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found"?
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... where's the autoloader?

Comment: I was under the impression the default autoload function would resolve namespaces into directory structures...?

Comment: nope. there isn't a default autoloader in php. after many years we have a standard that we can all follow, [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), and some different autoloader [implementation](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/) that you can use if you follow psr-0/4 specification

Comment: but if you use composer, let it build the autoloader it for you